# URL redirect in JavaScript Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have 2 form templates as modals (using Handlebars) in the page with the URL `/admin`:

```
<form  method="post" action="/admin1"></form> //form1
<form  method="post" action="/admin2"></form> //form2
```

In the routes.js file:

```
router.route('/admin').get( controller.index )
router.route('/admin1').get( controller.index )
router.get('/admin1/:sectionCode', controller.sectionForm )
    .post('/admin1/:sectionCode', controller.addStudents)
router.get('/admin/:sectionCode', controller.sectionForm )
    .post('/admin/:sectionCode', controller.addStudents)
```

In the controller.js:

```
async addStudents(req, res) {
        try {
            let section = req.body
            await sectionRepository.addStudentsToSection(section)
            res.redirect('/admin')
        }catch (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    }
```

Whether I submit form1 or form2, I do not get redirected to the original `/admin` page, and I get empty brackets in the blank page, although the url in the browser shows the correct url. Inspect in Chrome shows:

```
POST http://localhost:9001/admin 500 (Internal Server Error)
Navigated to http://localhost:9001/admin
```

How can I redirect to the same page as the forms are in: `/admin`?

Comment: it seems that you have internal error inside `controller.index`

Comment: If you are submitting your form through AJAX (or XMLHttpRequest), you wont be able to redirect like that. Only traditional HttpRequests can take advantage of res.redirect().